# Как менять цвет текста при клике?

Tags: javascript

Изучаю JavaScript. Хочу сделать, чтобы при клике на параграф текст в нём менял свой цвет на красный, а при повторном клике перекрашивался обратно в чёрный. Применил if, но если использую оператор повторно, то первый не работает. Интересует только вариант на чистом JS, не jQuery.

```js
function clickColor() {
 var d;
 d = document.getElementById('tagP');

 if (d.style.color='red') {
  d.style.color='black';
 }

 if (d.style.color='black') {
  d.style.color='red';
 }

 console.log(d.style.color);
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="countr">
  
  <p id="tagP" onclick="clickColor()">Россия</p>
  <p>Австрия</p>
  <p>Польша</p>
  <p>Латвия</p>
  <p>Чехия</p>

 </div>


 <script src="script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
for (var p of document.getElementsByTagName('p')) {
  // Берём все теги <p> и проходимся по каждому
  p.onclick = function() {
    // В функции onclick указываем цвет противоположный текущему (с тернарным оператором)
    this.style.color = this.style.color === 'red' ? 'black' : 'red';
  }
}
```

```html
<p>Россия</p>
<p>Австрия</p>
<p>Польша</p>
<p>Латвия</p>
<p>Чехия</p>
```

Разница между [`addEventListener()` и `onclick`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6348494/addeventlistener-vs-onclick)

Comment: Очень продвинутый вариант) Пошёл разбираться)

Comment: Но в ИЕ11 работать не будет, т.к. надо поддержка es6. И, да, солидарен с @Dantessss на счет нескольких обработчиков

Answer (score 3):

Вы в условиях `if` присваиваете значение, а не сравниваете. Используйте оператор `==` вместо `=`.

Comment: Точно. Спасибо)

Answer (score 1):

Есть возможность использовать делегирование событий, чтобы не создавать сотню обработчиков и уменьшить потребление памяти

```js
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if (e.target.tagName === 'P') {
    e.target.style.color = e.target.style.color === 'red' ? 'black' : 'red';
  }
});
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempora, pariatur.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempora, pariatur.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempora, pariatur.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempora, pariatur.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempora, pariatur.</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Tempora, pariatur.</p>
```